# Tizen post HTTP web service

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I'm trying to post HTTP in Tizen wearable native, but there is no sample project from their website; there is a code snippet but I don't know how to use the code. On Android the code 'volley' is easier to use and has more resources than Tizen.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads/http

Comment: check my answer and give feedback please

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample app for Curl on Tizen Studio.

### *File > New > Tizen Project > Sample > Mobile 2.4 > Native App > Network*

and select **Curl**

[image]